# Pantelides Algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

i am studying the pantelides alorithm and i need some help regarding a regular expression the pantelides alorithm located int he index.php of the main package @ http://jpye.dyndns.org/pantelides/

in the index.php file i see:

```
if(preg_match_all("#\\b([a-z][a-z_0-9]*)(?!\\()\\b#i",$str,$matches)){
```

now, i'm not an expert in reg exp but i know what [a-z] means but that is `\\b` means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

In a double-quoted php string you'll need to escape the backslash using another backslash. Thus, `"\\b"` is `'\b'`.

Comment: in the link you attached, its showing only 1 `\\` why this one has 2?

Comment: Because you used double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') as he already noted